# Как назначить z-index для подменю, чтобы спрятать тень?

Tags: css, wordpress, box-shadow

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Происходит наложение тени от подменю на меню. `z-index` бы помог, но где его назначить для подменю? Или как удалить тень с одной стороны? Сдвинуть тень по вертикали - не подходит. Т.к. тень разная получится.

Wordpress + Elementor + Тема Hello.

Comment: Первое что приходит в голову: значение `z-index` у меню должен быть больше, чем у подменю. Тогда меню будет накрывать тень у подменю и ее не будет видно.

Comment: Всё верно. Но, как назначить z-index для подменю отдельно от меню?

Comment: `.menu { z-index: 2; } .menu > .submenu { z-index: 1; }`

Comment: Этот код нужно вставить в style.css?

Comment: Да, но это пример, адаптируйте под свой код.